# R: using ifelse function for non-numerical values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have some trouble using the `ifelse` option.
I want to use this function in order to do a multiple linear regression.
I have a large dataset and most of the data are "NA" and some others are
words.
The idea is to have `NA = 0` and if not `NA` then it should be equal to 1.
So I've done :

```
dsp = ifelse (sp == "NA", 0, 1)
```

But when I print dsp : I can see that the non `NA` values are changed to `1` but
the `NA` values are not changed to `0` and are still the same.

I've tried the `is.na()` function, then I get `FALSE` for `NA` values and `TRUE` for non-NA values. I've tried `ifelse( dsp == "False", 0, 1)` but I have the same result as `dsp = ifelse (sp == "NA", 0, 1)`

Any idea about what should I do?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried `dsp = ifelse(is.na(sp), 0, 1)`?

Comment: Awesome it works ! THANK YOU !

Comment: And per @Maurits Evers comment, any time you wish to check for `NA`s in R, use `is.na()` and not `==`.

Comment: A code-golfing version could be `dsp <- +!(is.na(sp))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to replace all the `NA`s in the vector with `0` and if there is a value to `1`.

as @Maurits Evers said, you can do it like this:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))
```

In addition, you can get the same result using `case_when`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(
    is.na(x) ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ 1))
```

Also, you can do it with base R:

```
df[which(abs(df$x) >= 0), ] <- 1
df$x[is.na(df$x), ] <- 0
```

As suggested by @Tino, another base R option can be using `transform()` and `ifelse()`.

```
transform(df, x = ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))
```

sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 3))
```

Comment: `which()` should not be used for logical subsettting. Instead of `df[which(is.na(df$x)), ] <- 0` it is better to write `df[is.na(df$x), ] <- 0`

Comment: @DJV It should be `df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- 0` or just use `transform` as you would use `mutate` - it is base R as well: `transform(df, x = ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))`. Your solution would overwrite the entire row with either 0 or 1, not just the x-variable.

Answer (score -2):

Just add another line of code below your original code and it should work :

```
dsp = ifelse (sp == "NA", 0, 1)
dsp[is.na(dsp)]<-0
```